# Delete corrupted file using mathematica

Tags: image-processing, image, files-and-directories

I have a folder containing around 4000 JPEG files. Among those 4000 files most of are corrupted and can not be opened by any photo viewer. The below screenshot is a corrupted [JPEG file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B86Y4o9NLy2oRGRYVzBVWTJyVVE/view?usp=sharing) opened in windows photo viewer. 
[image]

Is it possible to delete those corrupted files using Mathematica "file operation"?

Comment: Can you link to one of those corrupted files?

Comment: @dan7geo find the hyperlink.

Comment: :/ A link to the screenshot of the corrupted file won't help. I need the actual file

Comment: @dan7geo check it now.

Answer (score 4):

Run the following to get a list of files in your directory (replace the path with the path to your directory):

```
files = FileNames@"C:\\Users\\dan7g\\Desktop\\*.JPG"
```

Then run the following to delete the corrupt files:

```
DeleteFile@Select[files, $Failed == Import@# &]
```

**Make sure you make a backup of the folder first, before doing this, in case something goes wrong.**